# Selecting the Datetimepicker resetting the other input fields in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, datetimepicker

I am new to Frontend development and trying to create a sample page in React in which I want to schedule the copy of selected files to the servers which are taken as input from user. For date time I am using DateTimePicker. My Page currently looks like this:

[image]

Here I am facing two issues:

1. If I enter the server values which are comma separated multiple servers and after that I select the time from Date Picker it's resetting the Server Textarea.
2. This is not related to issue but more about the suggestion. As you can see in the screenshot, there are some css alignment issues with the form. Please suggest me standard way to proceed with React Forms and which CSS to be used. There are bootstrap and if I am correct Formik is having it's own css. So bit confused, which one I should stick as a beginner so that my page looks fine.

Currently I am using Formik for this page but somehow not able to fix the css issue to make my page look atlease fine if not very good.

Please refer [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-aryabhata-rgkm2j) for this.

Comment: A sandbox/codepen would be helpful

Comment: @tpliakas updated the link the in post.